# Raspberry Pi 4 / mount network at boot

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I need access to a network drive with my Pi 4 (latest Buster). This also works via the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxx@root.lan,password=xxxxxx //xxshr9.root.lan/daten /home/pi/mnt
```

Now I want the whole thing to run automatically when I start it.
Unfortunately, this does not work.
I have tried the following ways so far without success:

- Insert the above command in the "/etc/rc.local".
- Create a service that calls a .sh file.
- I have also added the following line to "/etc/fstab":

> //xxshr9.root.lan/daten /home/pi/mnt cifs username=xxx@root.lan,password=xxxxxx 0 0

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please note that only programming questions are on-topic on SO.

Comment: have you tried a google search on `automount network drive raspberry pi`?  I don't work with Pi's but the results of the google search look promising; are you aware of the sister site: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: there is also https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.
I had to activate the function under "raspi-config" so that the Pi only boots when the network is loaded.